# simple SpringMVC maven project 404

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, http-status-code-404

I am learning SpringMVC, and I wrote a simple controller in IDEA. But I got a 404 Error.
Here is my code and error msg.

project structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mU3fo.jpg)

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
     version="4.0">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SpringMVC</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:springmvc-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SpringMVC</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

springmvc-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping" id="BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter" id="SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" id="InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB_INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

<bean id="/hello" class="com.scy.controller.HelloController"/>
```

HelloController.java

```
package com.scy.controller;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class HelloController implements Controller {

    @Override
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws Exception {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.addObject("msg", "Hello! SpringMVC~");
        mv.setViewName("hello");  // 通过前后缀拼接 --> /WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp
        return mv;
    }
}
```

hello.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

${msg}

</body>
</html>
```

here is my out file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5JPj.jpg)

here is TNFO output

```
26-Aug-2021 22:58:22.795 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
26-Aug-2021 22:58:22.966 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'SpringMVC'
```

I have been stuck in here for two days, could somebody help me?

Comment: Please provide the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), like a link to the project on GitHub. Do you run on embedded server or Tomcat?

Comment: Yes. And I solved it just now. 
I code "WEB_INF" instead of "WEB-INF"
I am soooo stupid